# aurora mysql 5.7 insert into failing

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7, amazon-aurora

Can't seems to figure this one out. I come from the SQL Server world but would expect this to work the same.

```
insert into active_directory (ad_account,email,distinguished_name,employee_id,manager_distinguished_name,display_name,terminated)
select
    ad_account,
    email,
    distinguished_name,
    employee_id,
    manager_distinguished_name,
    display_name,
    case when distinguished_name like '%Terminations%' then 1 else 0 end as terminated
from
    active_directory_staging
```

fails with this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'terminated)
select
    ad_account,
    email,
    distinguished_name,
    employee_id,
    mana' at line 1
```

if I remove the `terminated` column from the insert/select query it works fine. Add it back and it fails.

If I run just the select part (both with and without the case statement for the terminated column) it works fine.

I am probably just missing something basic here...any help is appreciated.

`active_directory` table create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `active_directory` (
  `ad_account` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `distinguished_name` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager_distinguished_name` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `terminated` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a bunch of reserved words that can't be used as column names/ alias.

Unfortunately for this query, `terminated` is one such word.

Excerpt from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html :

- ...
- TEMPORARY
- TEMPTABLE
- TERMINATED (R)
- TEXT
- THAN
- ...